# using flag-icon-css (npm package) with meteor

Tags: meteor, npm

I'm trying to use the npm package flag-icon-css with meteor.
I'm using sass to modify the icons path as follows:

```
$flag-icon-css-path: '/npm/node_modules/flag-icon-css/flags';
$flag-icon-rect-path: '/4x3';
$flag-icon-square-path: '/1x1';

@import '{}/node_modules/flag-icon-css/sass/flag-icon.scss';
```

but I'm stuck as i don't understand what is the correct path for the variable `$flag-icon-css-path` .

the question is simple : how can I access files that are in a npm package ? what is the correct path ? Do I need to export them all explicitly or something similar ?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that files from npm packages are not directly visible to the client. A solution should be to wrap the npm package in a meteor package and export what is needed to the client explicitly. In this case the solution is to use an already made package for this npm module : `meteor add jss:flag-icon`

Comment: Would still be nice to find a solution for referencing relative path based assets in scss when using node odules

Comment: I didn't try, but I think if the flags (in this case a bunch of svg files) were explicitly exported to the client , then the original scss snippet in my question would have worked. npm modules are server only and anything that should be visible client side must be declared manually. Maybe a better solution would be to have the sass pre-processor to export selected files for you to the client the same way this is done with the generated css... maybe ... in this case wrapping the npm module is a satisfying solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

NPM are packages that should be installed. It would then be able to directly adress it:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Go in the folder using the prompt, and execute:

```
npm install
```

Comment: I've already installed the package with ```meteor npm install```. Do I need to do anything else ?